# CUDA broadcast function for scalar

Tags: cuda

I find myself often use warp reduction in CUDA, then needing to broadcast (share) the scalar result amongst all threads.  My question is, what is the idiomatic way to do so with clean expressive code that is also efficient?  I wrote this simple template to do so, please review and comment.  Or if you know a better way, please share ;)

```
template <class T>
__inline__ __device__ T Share(T x) {
    __shared__ T shared;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        shared = x;
    __syncthreads();
    return shared;
}
```

Comment: "Warp reduction" indicates that there may be only 32 threads. Is that (always) the case, or are there more threads you want to share the result with?

Comment: @BlameTheBits If there is an efficient way to broadcast just to the warp, I'm interested.  But in general I need the scalar to be available to every thread in the thread block.

Comment: For one warp you could use [`__shfl_sync`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) (given a power of two of participating threads and a supported type `T`). Besides that I don't really have a helpful answer to your question. I think it fulfills it purpose and there is not much one can do different. Making the thread to sync from a function parameter is the only thing that comes to my mind - but you probably don't need that so there is no need to make it unnecessary generic and therefore more "complex".

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210650/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-broadcast-a-value-to-all-the-threads-after-using-blo